# Status of items added to TDS projects

Tags: tds, git

When adding items to my TDS project under Git resource control, VS adds a little lock to show me it's under source control.  However I have some items which are displaying a green plus sign (pending) or a red minus sign (ignored).  I've tried deleting the item from VS and then using Get Sitecore Items to get a fresh copy, but it doesn't stick.  The items aren't getting pushed up to Git because it doesn't notice the change.  How can I add these items?

Comment: Do you have something in your gitignore that is making them be ignored. Like in your gitignore you might have /bin/ and in your Sitecore/TDS you have an item called "bin".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds very much like you have items that are being ignored by your `.gitignore` file.

To find out what is being ignore, open a git command prompt (Git Bash/PowerShell/Command Prompt - whatever your choice of command line tool is) and run this:

```
git check-ignore -v filename
```

Where `filename` is the name and path of your TDS `.item` file. It will return you the line in the `.gitignore` file of the rule that is ignoring your file.

Example:
My `.gitignore` is setup to ignore my `.vs` folder. To check that I can run:

git check-ignore -v .vs

it would return

```
.gitignore:21:/.vs    .vs
```

The first part is the file adding the ignore rule, in this case `.gitignore`, the second part is the line number - `21` and the third part is the rule - `/.vs`

Once you have that you can either remove the rule or force the add. To force the add on the command line do:

```
git add --force path/filename
```

Then git will pick up that file and start tracking it for changes. If you are using a Gui for git, the method to force and add will change based on the tool.